# Building an $m \times n$ matrix from element-wise from two other such matches

Tags: matrix

I am a beginner with *Mathematica*. I have two matrices, `s1` and `s2`, and I am building a third matrix from them.

```
psi = 1/2 ArcTan[s1,s2]
```

I would like to add the following rule: if the corresponding elements of `s1` and `s2` are both  zero, then the  corresponding $\psi$ element must also be zero.

I tried with:

```
psi = 
  Table[
    If s1 == 0 && s2 == 0, psi[[i,j]] = 0, 1/2 ArcTan[s1[[i, j]], s2[[i, j]]],
    {i, 1280}, {j, 1024}]
```

but *Mathematica* got stuck running when I evaluated that.

Comment: What if you use `psi = Arg[s1 + I s2]/2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the value you are trying to remove is "Indeterminate", you can simply set all these to zero:

```
s1 = RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, {5, 5}];
s2 = RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, {5, 5}];
Quiet[1/2 ArcTan[s1, s2] //. Indeterminate -> 0. // N]
```

Comment: What does the last N mean?

Comment: If you place the cursor on the `N` and press F1, you can find out.

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1]
s1 = RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, {5, 5}];
s2 = RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, {5, 5}];
```

Temporarily define `Indeterminate` as `0`:

```
Block[{Indeterminate = 0}, 1./2 ArcTan[s1, s2]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]